# Is there a way to force sort columns for the Backlog view of Azure Devops?

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, ado, user-experience

In other views, you have to create various queries to get the results you want and change sorting, but the backlog view is a simple listing of team tasks and doesn't require extra steps. The only problem is that you can't sort the columns. I'm aware it's designed to be ordered and is displayed as such, but if I want to sort by columns, I should be able to.

Example board:
[image]

To fix this, I started with a simple script to add classes to the columns like so:

```js
function addSort(clicked){

    if ($(clicked).hasClass('up'))

        $(clicked).addClass('down').removeClass('up')

    else if ($(clicked).hasClass('down'))

        $(clicked).addClass('up').removeClass('down')

    else{

        // Clear all sorts

        $('.grid-header-column').removeClass('up').removeClass('down');

        // Sort up by default

        $(clicked).addClass('up');

    }

}

$('.grid-header-column').click(function(){

// defined as a function for easy testing because functions can be easily redefined on the fly through the console and jquery can't

addSort(this)

})
```

And it works... sort of. What I discovered is that, as you scroll, the content that is off the screen loads on the fly and also UNLOADS. For some reason, they decided that only the stuff that can fit on your screen should be displayed and it's making it impossible to hack the columns and manually sort them with javascript.

Is there a method I'm not thinking of to make this work? Some kind of hack to force ADO to show all the content at once on the page and leave it alone so I can work with it? Or, better yet, some way to trigger sortable columns on this view?

Comment: Can you share why you want to sort in backlog view? I noticed that it is very convenient to create a query with one click on the backlog.  The query result contains all the workitems in the backlog. Then you can sort the query results. See screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EShm1.png).

Comment: Yes, if I click twice, change screens, wait for it to load, click several more times, I can construct a query to show backlog items and order it. Then I can do it all again to order it differently. All to approximate a feature that is standard in pretty much any listing of data anywhere?

Comment: Currently, the Backlog page is designed like this. If you think this feature is necessary, you can also request a feature for Azure DevOps [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest).